# $geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context error with Mongo C driver

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

I'm using the [mongoc_collection_count_documents()](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.23.1/mongoc_collection_count_documents.html) function (driver version 1.23.1, MongoDB server version 5.0.13), this way:

```
long long n = mongoc_collection_count_documents(collection, q, NULL, NULL, NULL, &error);
```

where `q` is a `bson_t` variable that depends on the particular query.

With simple queries like `{"score": 20}` it works fine. However, if I try something something like this:

```
{
    "location" : {
        "$near" : {
            "$geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                    2,
                    1
                ]
            },
            "$maxDistance" : 10
        }
    }
}
```

(I have a `2dsphere` index for `location` field)

I get the following error:

```
$geoNear, $near, and $nearSphere are not allowed in this context
```

On the contrary, if I run the same query with `db.c.count()` at the Mongo Shell I don't get any error.

So I have two questions:

- Why `count()` at the Mongo Shell works but `mongoc_collection_count_documents()` doesn't? Aren't they based in the same underlying operation?
- How I can get a count of document for queries using `$near` etc. with Mongo C driver?

Comment: Does this help: http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.23.1/mongoc_collection_count_documents.html#migrating-from-deprecated-count-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [the link provided by @Joe](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.23.1/mongoc_collection_count_documents.html#migrating-from-deprecated-count-functions) I have find the suggestion to use `$geoWithin` with `$center` instead of `$near`.

The problem is that `$geoWithin` doesn't have a equivalence for `$near`'s `$minDistance`. However, looking to [this ticket at MongoDB JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-12834) the query can be formulated this way (e.g. being 10 max distance and 5 min distance):

```
{
  $and: [
    { location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ 2, 1 ], 10 ] } } },
    { location: { $not: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ 2, 1 ], 5 ] } } } }
  ]
}
```

More complicated, but it suffices my case (although I wonder why the "compact way" is now considered deprecated in count functions...)